# Lost and Found Part 2 - Karn's Helmet

Tags: darksiders-2

I've just about cleared out the Drenchfort with no sign of Karn's Helmet. Where is this thing hiding at?

Comment: wait wait wait, this is out? O.o

Comment: Came out Today! Didn't see anyone asking questions so figured I'd start throwing stuff around :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the Drenchfort, you'll need to take the east hallway and then the first door to the south instead of going to the top where you release the water.

It's on a brazier kinda thingie in the far right corner of the room.